# Perform Logical AND on 2 separate JavaRDD

Tags: apache-spark

I have a very simple requirement where I need to do an operation similar to Logical AND on corresponding elements of 2 separate JavaRDD with same number of elements.
I'm trying to see if this can be done without collecting the elements into memory and performing the function.

I'm trying to avoid

```
JavaRDD<String> set1;
JavaRDD<String> set2;
List<String> list1 = set1.collect();
List<String> list2 = set2.collect();
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i< list1.size(); i++) {
    list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i)) ? result.add(i, 1) : result.add(i,0);
}
```

Is this possible to do it distributed? Both my JavaRDD are in order of GB.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `set1.zip(set2)` to combine both sets element-wise.

According to your example, something similar to

```
JavaRDD<Integer> result = set1.zip(set2).map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, Integer>() {
    public Integer call(Tuple2<String, String> t) {
        if (t._1().equals(t._2()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
})
```